# How to positon widgets placed in Absolute Panel on Browser Window resize in GWT?

Tags: gwt, window-resize

I have placed all the widgets inside an absolut panel.

when I minimize the window,the images gets cropped and also the positioning is not correct.

Can anyone out there help me out??

Comment: You should at least post some code

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [resizeHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#addResizeHandler%28com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ResizeHandler%29) to the `Window` class and then re-position your widget in the `onResize` callback.

```
Window.addResizeHandler(new ResizeHandler() {
     @Override
     void onResize(ResizeEvent event) {

          // Re-position your widgets
          // you can call event.getHeight() and event.getWidth() to get new dimensions
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your Response.Wen i added resize event handler and changing the height and width it worked..but the prob comes when the page is loaded in minimised position..scrolling is not appearing..I have used Window.getclientheight() for rootpanel..and corresponding heights for other widgets..

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If you want to have a scrollpanel, you have to either use GWT's ``ScrollPanel`` or change the ``overflow`` setting via css to **auto**